# SendGrid Dynamic Templates - get recipient email in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, sendgrid

In my SendGrid dynamic template, I need to get the recipient email and pass it in the URL. Is there any way I can the recipient email from some sort of global/default variables, or I will need to pass it with the payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass all the data that you want to use within the body of an email template in the dynamic template data.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for the next person looking.

You can get this via [handlebar keywords](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/editor#reserved-substitution-tags) Sendgrid provides if you are using Sendgrid Contacts

ex. `{{email}}` will substitute the to address of the contact in the template.